# Re.re and sexp.opaque : cannot compile

Tags: ocaml

I cannot compile successfully the following code

```
open Base
open Sexplib.Std
module Myregexp = struct
  type t =
    | Default
    | Regexp of
        { re : (Re.re [@sexp.opaque])
        ; a : int
        }
  [@@deriving sexp]
  let default = Default
end
```

The associated `dune` file :

```
(library (name myregexp)
 (libraries base re sexplib) (preprocess (pps ppx_jane ppx_sexp_conv)))
```

And the build command is : `dune build myregexp.a`.

I get the error :

```
File "myregexp.ml", line 9, characters 16-21:
Error: Unbound value Re.re_of_sexp
```

This should not occur thanks to `[@sexp.opaque]` statement (which will avoid to return a sexp form from `Re.re` see [janestreet ppx_sexp_conv](https://github.com/janestreet/ppx_sexp_conv))

I am using `ocaml-4.07.1`.

Comment: which version of ppx_sexp_conv are you using? I believe they added it only in v0.12. (The changelog is of little help though)

Comment: I've just migrated to v0.12 (I was using v0.11.2 before), but no progress. I have also tried with sexp_opaque instead of sexp.opaque, but it is still failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that this feature is not yet released to the public, probably it will be released as a part of the `v0.13` release.

If we will look into the README file of the latest to the date (April 2019) ppx_sexp_conv package, we won't find any mentions of the `[@sexp.opaque]`

```
$ opam source ppx_sexp_conv.v0.12.0
$ grep sexp.opaque ppx_sexp_conv.v0.12.0/README.org 
converters, simply apply the qualifier =sexp_opaque= as if it were a
  type foo = int * stuff sexp_opaque [@@deriving sexp]
```

As we see, only the old `sexp_opaque` trick. So what is left to us at the current point of time is to use it, e.g.,

```
 type t =
    | Default
    | Regexp of
        { re : Re.re sexp_opaque;
        ; a : int
        }
```

The `'a sexp_opaque` type constructor is defined as `'a sexp_opaque = 'a` except that sexp converters will treat it is an opaque element.

Most likely, this will break with the future releases of JS libraries, so I would suggest you a more wordy but stable solution:

```
type regex = Re.t
let sexp_of_regex = sexp_of_opaque
let regex_of_sexp = opaque_of_sexp

type t =
  | Default
  | Regexp of
    { re : regex;
    ; a : int
    }
 [@@deriving sexp]
```